# Magento 2 can't change host in env.php

Tags: magento2, database

I want to use a remote host for my magento 2. the problem is even if I have set the host to remote in env.php, it is still using localhost. it seems the value for the host is just ignored.

```
   array (
    'model' => 'mysql4',
    'engine' => 'innodb',
    'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
    'host' => 'my_remote_host',
    'dbname' => 'my_db',
    'username' => 'my_username',
    'password' => 'my_password',
    'active' => '1',
  ),
```

I have cleared the cache by using.

```
  php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I have cleared the cache in browser too.
It looks like my Magento 2 is simply ignore the value i set to the Host in env.php and keep using localhost as default.

Comment: Remove var directory once and test it in private mode of browser.

Comment: Change file permission, Please check you file permission

Comment: I have deleted everything in var folder, and clear cache in browser, same problem. The value I set to Host in env.php is simply ignored. and it is keep using localhost as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why, it was because in Magento 2. if you have typed in a wrong **remote host**, which was in my case. then **localhost** will be using.

Answer (score 0):

here you can see working configuration of `env.php`.

> `return array (
>   ...
>
>   'db' =>    array (
>       'table_prefix' => '',
>       'connection' => 
>       array (
>         'default' => 
>         array (
>           'host' => 'mysql56.sty',
>           'dbname' => '***',
>           'username' => '***',
>           'password' => '***',
>           'active' => '1',
>         ),
>       ),
>   ),
>   'resource' =>    array (
>     'default_setup' => 
>       array (
>         'connection' => 'default',
>       ),
>     ),
>
>   ...
>   );`

This file works fine at my local installation.